# Magento 2 : How can I add an extra path to the DirectoryList

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, directory

I want to be able to make Magento aware of an extra folder in my root called `private_files`. I thought I could do this by adding the following to my `di.xml`:

```
<!--
    Make Magento aware of an extra directory:
-->
<type name="Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="private_files" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">private_files</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

So I could get the directory in my code like so:

```
$mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead('private_files');
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Why is this? I noticed that if I make errors in my XML on purpose they don't get picked up if I put a `die()` in `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::assertCode()`.

Can `magento/framework`-classes and settings not be manipulated with `di.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

The allowed folders are listed in the following file: **vendor/magento/framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php**

```
    public static function getDefaultConfig()
{
    $result = [
        self::ROOT => [parent::PATH => ''],
        self::APP => [parent::PATH => 'app'],
        self::CONFIG => [parent::PATH => 'app/etc'],
        self::LIB_INTERNAL => [parent::PATH => 'lib/internal'],
        self::VAR_DIR => [parent::PATH => 'var'],
        /** @deprecated  */
        self::VAR_EXPORT => [parent::PATH => 'var/export'],
        self::CACHE => [parent::PATH => 'var/cache'],
        self::LOG => [parent::PATH => 'var/log'],
        self::DI => [parent::PATH => 'generated/metadata'],
        self::GENERATION => [parent::PATH => Io::DEFAULT_DIRECTORY],
        self::SESSION => [parent::PATH => 'var/session'],
        self::MEDIA => [parent::PATH => 'pub/media', parent::URL_PATH => 'media'],
        self::STATIC_VIEW => [parent::PATH => 'pub/static', parent::URL_PATH => 'static'],
        self::PUB => [parent::PATH => 'pub', parent::URL_PATH => ''],
        self::LIB_WEB => [parent::PATH => 'lib/web'],
        self::TMP => [parent::PATH => 'var/tmp'],
        self::UPLOAD => [parent::PATH => 'pub/media/upload', parent::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
        self::TMP_MATERIALIZATION_DIR => [parent::PATH => 'var/view_preprocessed/pub/static'],
        self::TEMPLATE_MINIFICATION_DIR => [parent::PATH => 'var/view_preprocessed'],
        self::SETUP => [parent::PATH => 'setup/src'],
        self::COMPOSER_HOME => [parent::PATH => 'var/composer_home'],
        self::GENERATED => [parent::PATH => 'generated'],
        self::GENERATED_CODE => [parent::PATH => Io::DEFAULT_DIRECTORY],
        self::GENERATED_METADATA => [parent::PATH => 'generated/metadata'],
        self::VAR_IMPORT_EXPORT => [parent::PATH => 'var', parent::URL_PATH => 'import_export']
    ];
    return parent::getDefaultConfig() + $result;
}
```

If we need to add some additional folder in the root folder of Magento, we must add the folder name in the array $result.

But this method cannot be overwritten because it is static. We will have to look at where it is used and perform some rewriting there.

Remember to give the folder write permission for the user or group.